# Azure Portal - Assign tags to Resource Groups using Powershell and reading data from Excel spreadsheet or CSV

Tags: excel, tags, azure-powershell, azureportal, azure-resource-group

I am looking to apply a new set of tags to a number of Azure Resource Groups. The tags must adhere to a naming convention which is a concatenation of a number of Microsoft Excel column data field values and will be read row by row for each Resource Group.

For example, let's use the below as an example of the first 6 columns:

Column A: Azure Subscription Name
Column B: Resource Group Name
Column C: Business Unit
Column D: Cost Center
Column E: Project Code
Column F: Service or Application Name

[image]

The proposed tag will then be a concatenation of for example:

**[Column A] - [Column B] - [Column C] - [Column E] - [Column F]**

The resultant tag for the first row should therefore look like the below example:

**"Subscription 1 : RG-01 : BU-A1 : 1001 : WebApp-1"**

Powershell would probably be the preferred solution to complete this task and I'd welcome any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: can you please explain more about your example? you have 6 columns, then the tags for resource group should use A+B+C+xx as value for 1 tag, or there are 6 tags like A,B,C?

Comment: @IvanYang, I just updated the original question with an illustration that should hopefully clarify things better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer 0406:**

The scripts below can work on multi-rows scenario:

Note: to use [Set-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-5.7.0#parameters) cmdlet, please install [Az.Accounts 2.2.7 module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Accounts/2.2.7).

```
#load the .csv file
$file_path = "D:\test\t1.csv"

#define the tag name, you can change it as per your need
$tag_name="mytag111"


#loop the values in the .csv file
Import-Csv -Path $file_path | ForEach-Object{

#define a tag value with empty string
$tag_value=""

#define a variable for subscription name
$subscription_name = ""

#define a variable for resource group name
$resource_group_name = ""

foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
{

 #here, get the subscription name from the csv file
 if($property.name -eq "Az Sub Name"){
        $subscription_name = $property.Value
   }
 #here, get the resource group name from the csv file
 if($property.name -eq "RG Name"){
        $resource_group_name = $property.Value
   }

  #exclude the "Cost Ctr" column
  if(!($property.name -eq "Cost Ctr"))
  {
    #then we loop all the values from each row, and then concatenate them
    #here, we just don't want to add the colon(:) at the end of the value from "Svc/App" column
    if(!($property.name -eq "Svc/App"))
    {  
    $tag_value += $property.Value + " : "
    }
    else
    {
    $tag_value += $property.Value
    }
  } 
 
}

#change the context as per different subscription
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription_name

#get the existing tags for the resource group
$tags = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resource_group_name).Tags
#add the new tags to the existing tags, so the existing tags will not be removed
$tags +=@{$tag_name=$tag_value}
#set the tags
Set-AzResourceGroup -Name $resource_group_name -Tag $tags

}

"completed********"
```

Here are the test data:

[image]

The scripts work fine as per my testing. And please let me know if you have any issues about it.

---

**Original answer:**

Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

I write a simple code to read data from .csv file and then add tags to the resource group.

**Note that** in my testing, there is only 1 row data in .csv file and hard-cord the resource group name, please feel free to modify the code to meet your requirement.

And to use the [Set-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azresourcegroup?view=azps-5.7.0) cmdlet, you should make sure the [Az.Resources](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Resources/3.4.0) module is installed.

**The .csv file:**

[image]

**The powershell code:**

```
#load the .csv file
$file_path = "D:\test\t1.csv"

#define the tag name, you can change it as per your need
$tag_name="mytag111"
#define a tag value with empty string
$tag_value=""

#loop the values in the .csv file
Import-Csv -Path $file_path | ForEach-Object{

foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties)
{
  #exclude the "Cost Ctr" column
  if(!($property.name -eq "Cost Ctr"))
  {
    #then we loop all the values from each row, and then concatenate them
    #here, we just don't want to add the colon(:) at the end of the value from "Svc/App" column
    if(!($property.name -eq "Svc/App"))
    {
    $tag_value += $property.Value + " : "
    }
    else
    {
    $tag_value += $property.Value
    }
  } 
 
}

#get the existing tags for the resource group
$tags = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name yyrg11).Tags
#add the new tags to the existing tags, so the existing tags will not be removed
$tags +=@{$tag_name=$tag_value}
#set the tags
Set-AzResourceGroup -Name yyrg11 -Tag $tags

}

"completed********"
```

**The test result:**

[image]

**In azure portal, the tag is added:**

[image]

Comment: that looks absolutely brilliant !! 
I am most definitely going to give it a go and then provide some feedback. And just to clarify, I believe you've indicated that any existing tags will be retained, is that right?

Your wonderful contribution is greatly appreciated and I'll be providing some feedback shortly.

Comment: I have tried your script and I think it may be defective. Rather than only having a single row as your input data file, please replicate my sample data by running your script against multiple rows like I presented in my original query which had 4 rows. Otherwise, your proposed solution isn't quite replicating the test case.

Comment: @hitman126 first, yes, any existing tags will be retained. Second, I think it's easy to modify the code for multi-rows, so just for testing purpose, I wrote a very simple script. Don't worry, I will update the code later for multi-rows.

Comment: @hitman126 I've updated my answer including multi-rows scenario. Please give it a try and let me know if you have any issues about the scripts:).

Comment: Hi @Ivan Yang, I most definitely will. I'm hoping to give the updated script a try very shortly and will provide some feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: @hitman126 hello, have you tried it? please let me know the updates:)

Comment: I have tested the script and I'm happy to confirm that it works perfectly, having only required me to initialise the $subscription_name variable. Much appreciated. I do however have one minor change to request. Within the If condition block, you excluded the column "Cost Ctr". My actual scenario requires more columns to be excluded. Could you therefore kindly update the script to exclude for example 3 columns (you can pick any random names for the other two columns). Alternatively, could you simply refine the script to execute on the 5 tag columns only, with no exclude condition?

Comment: Hi @Ivan Yang, yes of course I will definitely mark it as the answer. Sincere apologies. I meant to do that earlier. Do you however still require me to submit a separate question for the enhancement requested? I'd personally prefer it being part of this question as it's directly related.

Comment: @hitman126 it would be good if you can raise a new question:). Just let me know the url.